# Angular.js issue: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

Hi everybody I am trying to follow a video lesson of Angular.js I added ng-app at the html tag, the ng-controller in the body to use the controller but I see all the {{elements}}. (If I remove the ng-controller, the input field works fine, but when I try to add the ng-controller, starts the problems... in the following code I should show only a list of authors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
   <title>AngularJS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="bg-secondary" ng-controller="MyController">
   <div class="container mt-sm-3">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title text-dark">Directory degli Artisti</h2>

              <div class="form-row mb-2">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="col-form-label text-right" for="searchQuery">search {{' for: ' + query}}</label>
                </div><!-- label -->

                <div class="col-12">
                  <input  class="form-control form-control-lg" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Search for artists" autofocus ng-model="query">
                </div><!-- col-12 -->
              </div><!-- form-row -->

          </div><!-- card-body -->
      </div><!-- col-12 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- col-container -->

<div class="artist-list container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5">
        <ul class=" list-group d-flex">
          <li class="list-group-item">

              <div class="media d-flex align-items-center">
                <img class="rounded-circle mr-3"
                  src="images/{{artist.shortname}}_tn.jpg"
                  alt="Photo of {{artist.name}}">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h5 class="my-0 text-dark">{{artist.name}} </h5>
                  <div class="text-secondary font-italic">{{artist.study}}</div>
                </div><!-- media-body -->
              </div><!-- media -->

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- col-12 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- col-container -->

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

The file app.js, contains the list of author (only one in my example) is the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []); // no dipendenze []

myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

   $scope.artist = {
      "name":"Emilio Alfieri",
      "shortname":"Draco",
      "study":"Ing. Informatica",
      "bio":"Nato a Roma il 7/05/1987, si è sposato il 19 Agosto 2020 in Indonesia.Adora la chitarra e i computers."
   }
 }); //$scope è come una variabile globale
```

I receive the following error:  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
I really followed all the instruction I have seen in the video. What's my mistake?

Thank you very much!

  -

Comment: Hi Emilio. I suggest, for a little more clarity, would you please show the link to the "video lesson" you refer to in, "I am trying to follow a video lesson of Angular.js". Thanks.

Comment: it is on linkedin learning so It's not accessible free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a spelling mistake of module name.

Replace  `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);`

instead  of 
`var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
   $scope.artist = {
      "name":"Emilio Alfieri",
      "shortname":"Draco",
      "study":"Ing. Informatica",
      "bio":"Nato a Roma il 7/05/1987, si è sposato il 19 Agosto 2020 in Indonesia.Adora la chitarra e i computers."
   }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
   <title>AngularJS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body  class="bg-secondary" ng-controller="MyController">
   <div class="container mt-sm-3">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title text-dark">Directory degli Artisti</h2>

              <div class="form-row mb-2">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="col-form-label text-right" for="searchQuery">search {{' for: ' + query}}</label>
                </div><!-- label -->

                <div class="col-12">
                  <input  class="form-control form-control-lg" id="searchQuery" placeholder="Search for artists" autofocus ng-model="query">
                </div><!-- col-12 -->
              </div><!-- form-row -->

          </div><!-- card-body -->
      </div><!-- col-12 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- col-container -->

<div class="artist-list container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5">
        <ul class=" list-group d-flex">
          <li class="list-group-item">

              <div class="media d-flex align-items-center">
                <img class="rounded-circle mr-3"
                  src="images/{{artist.shortname}}_tn.jpg"
                  alt="Photo of {{artist.name}}">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h5 class="my-0 text-dark">{{artist.name}} </h5>
                  <div class="text-secondary font-italic">{{artist.study}}</div>
                </div><!-- media-body -->
              </div><!-- media -->

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- col-12 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- col-container -->

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you it was just spelling mistake! Thank you @Supercool!